# Does URL parser work on questions posted on meta only?

Tags: discussion

On Super User, I tried pasting a URL that belongs to Unix. It didn't get parsed; it just stayed the same. A while ago I posted a URL on Meta Ask Ubuntu that belongs to Ask Ubuntu. I think the title of the question was extracted and displayed in href, rather than `http...`

Where on SE does the URL parser, that extract the title of the questions, work?